# Can't find the event or signal's name of mouse hoverenter event in QTreeView

Tags: qt, qtreeview, mousehover

I want to find the Event or Signal when mouse hover on a column like I showed in the pic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLJcB.png)

Comment: I don't see a mouse cursor in that pic. And what you try to hover on is unclear. Are you sure you uploaded the correct image?

Comment: Sry I reuploaded the correct image with mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

`QTreeView` inherits `QAbstractItemView`. `QAbstractItemView` has [entered(const QModelIndex &index)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#entered) signal.

Additionally `QTreeWidget` which inherits `QTreeView`, has [itemEntered(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemEntered) signal.

Comment: Thx for answering.